# What is the value of the integral F(a)?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Given that:
$$\int_a^T f(x) \,dx = F(T)$$
Doesn't this mean $F(a) = 0$, because  I found the equation:
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \left.F(x)\right\rvert_a^b = F(b)-F(a) $$
and I wondered what's the point of putting $F(a)$ if it equals to zero.

Comment: The two $a$’s are meaning different. You can modify the former to $\displaystyle \int_c^d f(x) \, d x = F(x) \rvert_{c}^{d} = F(d) - F(c)$, which doesn’t change the essence.

Comment: In your first equation $F$ is one specific primitive of $f$. The second formula holds for any primitive $F$.

Comment: Do you mean that the second equation takes that the possible constants into consideration $F+C$, and if so how is that? @Brifa

Comment: The first equation defines one specific primitive of $f$, namely the one for which $F(a)=0$. The second equation is true for any primitive $F+c$.